# Display page hierarchy on "Content" page of Admin Panel

Tags: users, nodes, dashboard

I'm currently working on a  Drupal application that has two content types (Floors, and Things). I'm using the Node Hierarchy module to declare child pages. The current structure goes something like this.

- Floor 1

  - Floor 2

    - Floor 3
    - Floor 4

      - Thing 1
    - Floor 5

...etc

I'm looking for a way to display this relationship on the admin dashboard instead of just having Drupal list every piece of content I want to have some sort of indication that one piece of content is a child of another.

Does anyone know of a module that can do this for me, or a way I can implement this myself?

Cheers

Comment: try https://drupal.org/project/views_tree

Comment: I'll look into it, just curious, cheers.

Comment: D6 or D7 version ?

Comment: Drupal 7. Sorry - I should've specified that.